# Irreducibility of a given polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification

> Consider the polynomial $a_4x^4+a_3x^3+a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0$, where $a_3,a_2$ are even integers and $a_4,a_1,a_0$ are odd integers. I want to determine whether this polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

My solution: Irreducibility over $\mathbb{Q}$ is the same as irreducibility over $\mathbb{Z}$. If we can demonstrate irreducibility over $\mathbb{Z}_n$ for some integer $n$, then we can demonstrate irreducibility over $\mathbb{Z}$. SO in this case choose $n=2$ ; the polynomial reduces to $x^4+x+1$, but this doesn't factor over $\mathbb{Z}_2$. Therefore this polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}_2$, therefore over $\mathbb{Z}$, and thus $\mathbb{Q}$.

Is this correct?

Comment: You still need to show that $x^4+x+1$ is irreducible over $\Bbb F_2$. That it has no root there is not enough. Your claim "but this doesn't factor over $\Bbb F_2$" has no proof yet.

Comment: Irreducibility over $\mathbf Q$ is the same as irreducibility over $\mathbf Z$ *only* if the polynomial is primitive (meaning the coefficients have gcd $1$).  For example, the polynomial $f(x) = 3x^4 + 6x^3 + 6x^2 + 3x + 3$ fits your conditions but it is not irreducible over $\mathbf Z$ since it is $3(x^4 + 2x^3 + 2x^2 + x + 1)$ and that is a factorization into two nonunits in $\mathbf Z[x]$.

Comment: To add to @DietrichBurde, there is still a possibility that $x^4+x+1=p(x)\cdot q(x)$ for irreducible quadratic polynomials $p$ and $q$.

Comment: The proof is salvageable: if the polynomial factors as $p(x)\cdot q(x)$, then by adjusting constants we may assume $p$ and $q$ both have leading coefficient have no $2$ in their denominators. Now, by standard arguments none of the coefficients have $2$ in their denominators. Thus, you can reduce modulo $2$.

Answer (score 1):

First note that irreducibility in Q and Z are equivalent only for primative polynomials.

If you manage to show that the polynomial is primative(Which I'm not sure can be deduced), your proof is correct, but it is not trival that x^4 + x + 1 is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Suppose that x^4 + x + 1 = g(x)f(x). We know that $deg(g) + deg(f) = deg(x^4+x+1) = 4$. So there are three possbilities(Other than swapping the degrees of the two polynomials):

- $deg(g) = 2, deg(f) = 2$
- $deg(g) = 3, deg(f) = 1$
- $deg(g) = 4, deg(f) = 0$

Now we can show that the first two cases are not possible, and therefore it must be that $deg(f) = 0$ which means it is a unit(Since every deg 0 polynomial is a unit) and any factorization of $x^4+x+1$ would be into a unit.

Suppose that $deg(g) = 2, deg(f) = 2$. Let $g(x) = x^2 + bx + c$ and $f(x) = x^2 + dx + k$
Then we have that:
$$
x^4 + x + 1 = (x^2 + bx + c)(x^2 + dx + k)\\
x^4 + x + 1 = x^4 + (b+d)x^3 + (bd + c + k)x^2 + (bk + cd)x + ck\\
$$
Where $b,d,c,k \in \mathbb{Z}_2$ we can derive a contradiction. Since $ck = 1$ it must be that $c = k = 1$. But we also need to maintain the quadratic term that $bd + c + k = 1$. Since now we know that $c + k = 0$ we can reduce this down to $bd = 1$.

The linear term gives us that $bk + cd = 1$ which now reduces to $b + d = 1$. But there is no solution in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ for $b + d = bd = 1$.

An equivalent(and equally tedious argument) show that you can't have $deg(g)=3,deg(f)=1$.

Thus you know that one of the factors must be a unit and that $x^4+x+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_2$